# How to extract a part of xml code from an xml file using Perl Script and move to separate files

Tags: xml, perl

I need a Perl Script to do the following process:

See the following XML code:

```
<booklist>
  <book>
    <author>Book 1 author 1</author>
    <author>Book 1 author 2</author>
    <title>Book 1 title</title>
    <isbn>Book1ISBN</isbn>
  </book>
  <book>
    <author>Book 2 author 1</author>
    <author>Book 2 author 2</author>
    <title>Book 2 title</title>
    <isbn>Book2ISBN</isbn>
  </book>
  <book>
    <author>Book 3 author 1</author>
    <author>Book 3 author 2</author>
    <author>Book 3 author 3</author>
    <title>Book 3 title</title>
    <isbn>Book3ISBN</isbn>
  </book>
</booklist>
```

how can i extract the portion

```
<book>
    <author>Book 3 author 1</author>
    <author>Book 3 author 2</author>
    <author>Book 3 author 3</author>
    <title>Book 3 title</title>
    <isbn>Book3ISBN</isbn>
</book>
```

and move to separate XML file using Perl?

Comment: How will you identify which book you want? By title? ISBN? Position relative to some other element?

Comment: That's the 3rd time you ask the same question, changing just the format of the XML file: [How to extract a part of xml code from an xml file using Perl Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074154/extract-xml-tags-using-perl) and [Extract XML tags using Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074939/how-to-extract-a-part-of-xml-code-from-an-xml-file-using-perl-script).

Answer (score 2):

You could use XML::Twig like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $t= XML::Twig->new( twig_roots => { book => \&book }, 
                       pretty_print => 'indented',
                     )
                ->parsefile( 'books.xml');

sub book
  { my( $t, $book)= @_;
    my $isbn= $book->field( 'isbn');
    if( $isbn eq 'Book3ISBN')
      { $book->cut->print_to_file( "$isbn.xml"); }
    else 
      { $t->flush; }
  }
```

This assumes that you are selecting the book to extract based on its ISBN, and that you want to output the initial file without that book.

If the criteria is something else, then adjust the test in `book`.

If you don't want to touch the original file, then remove the call to `cut`, and replace `flush` by `purge` (these methods throw away the previous elements in the tree so you don't use too much memory, if the initial file is small, then you don't need them)